# Runtime error in using wordnet through JWNL

Tags: java, wordnet

I am trying to access Wordnet using JWNL.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JWNLException {
    // Initialize the database
    WordNetHelper.initialize("file_properties.xml");
}
```

Getting runtime exception in the line where I initialize file_properties.xml which says,
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory"

I have configured the file to point to dictionary files by giving the path as, 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\3.0\dict"

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

looks like case of missing jar from classpath.

Add lib/commons-logging.jar to classpath.

Should solve your problem.